# Jest gives an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"

Tags: jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my React app.

Recently, I added [DeckGL](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl) to my app. My tests fail with this error:

```
Test suite failed to run

/my_project/node_modules/deck.gl/src/react/index.js:21
export {default as DeckGL} from './deckgl';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:318:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/deck.gl/dist/react/deckgl.js:9:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/deck.gl/dist/react/index.js:7:15)
```

This looks like an issue with Jest transforming a node module before running it's tests.

Here is my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
}
```

Here is my jest setup:

```
"jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/jestsetup.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "/src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/test/EmptyModule.js"
    }
  },
```

I seem to have the correct things necessary to transform `export {default as DeckGL }`. So any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: Did you forgot to add a semicolon to the line above the export?

Comment: @DonP, can you try using the recommended [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest) and see if it helps? I don't want to crowd this question with another answer if it doesn't help you out

Comment: Nothing here helped but https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2537#issuecomment-390341713 mentioned you can pass in `transformIgnorePatterns` as a command-line argument to `npm`/`yarn`/`craco` in package.json's `scripts`, and that worked!

Answer (score 194):

This means, that a file is not transformed through TypeScript compiler, e.g. because it is a JS file with TS syntax, or it is published to npm as uncompiled source files. Here's what you can do.

Adjust your `transformIgnorePatterns` allowed list:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@ngrx|(?!deck.gl)|ng-dynamic)"
    ]
  }
}
```

By default Jest doesn't transform node_modules, because they should be valid JavaScript files. However, it happens that library authors assume that you'll compile their sources. So you have to tell this to Jest explicitly. Above snippet means that @ngrx, deck and ng-dynamic will be transformed, even though they're node_modules.

Comment: Had to combine this with @Jimi Pajala's answer to get things to work when running tests.

Comment: What is the reason for the nested negative lookahead `(?!...(?!...))` in the regex?

Comment: where do I put this? which file?

Comment: @EladKatz I'm new to this, but I think this block is meant for package.json, and without the 'jest' wrapper you could put it in jest.config.js.

Comment: Might just want to simplify the RegExp like this: `node_modules\/(?!(@ngrx|deck.gl|ng-dynamic))`

Comment: This works for me, in my case Jest can't deal with imports from `lodash-es`. Whitelisting the package like this resolves the issue.

Comment: @EladKatz in the `jest.config.js` file.

Comment: This has fixed my tests but has made the tests long. Around 1 minute per test.

Comment: this helped some of my tests pass, but then a bunch failed with the following... any thoughts?

    SyntaxError: C:\Code\altitude-traffic\client\node_modules\domino\lib\sloppy.js: 'with' in strict mode. (10:4)

       8 |   Window_run: function _run(code, file) {
       9 |     if (file) code += '\n//@ sourceURL=' + file;
    > 10 |     with(this) eval(code);
         |     ^
      11 |   },
      12 |   EventHandlerBuilder_build: function build() {
      13 |     try {

Comment: my pkg files are in es6, and everything is like as you said, but adding `"<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(THE_PKG)/)",` does not makes any difference and i still get the same `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` which point to the module that i'm trying to import from that es6 package

Answer (score 65):

And if you are using 'create-react-app', it won't allow you to specify *'transformIgnorePatterns'* via Jest property in *package.json*

As per this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2537#issuecomment-390341713

You can use CLI as below in your *package.json* to override and it works :

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!your-module-name)/\"",
},
```

Comment: CRA [3.0.2 added](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6055#event-2419503373) support for Jest `transformIgnorePatterns` in package.json.

Comment: Worth noting that if you're using `react-app-rewired`, it takes over the processing for the `jest` property in `package.json`, and concatenates rather than replaces. So this solution will not work and you will have to place it in the script options or inside the overrides script

Answer (score 40):

This is because Node.js cannot handle ES6 modules.

You should transform your modules to CommonJS therefore.

**Babel 7** >=

Install
`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`

And to use only for test cases add to .babelrc,
Jest automatically gives NODE_ENV=test global variable.

```
"env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}
```

**Babel 6 >=**

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`

to .babelrc

```
"env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! However, make sure to run `jest --clearCache` I had to do that before it started working.

Comment: where do I add:

"env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}

Comment: @joeCarpenter to your `.babelrc` or to other babel config file you might be using eg `babel.config.js`. If you don't yet have one you can create new file in the project root with name `.babelrc` and add this under root `{  }` -tags.

Comment: Had to combine this answer with @Ria Anggraini's answer to get things to work when running tests.

Answer (score 21):

Jest by default won't compile files in the `node_modules` directory.

> [transformIgnorePatterns](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string) [array]
>
> Default: ["/node_modules/"]
>
> An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source
>   file paths before transformation. If the test path matches any of the
>   patterns, it will not be transformed.Default: ["/node_modules/"]

DeckGL seems to be in ES6, to make jest able to read it, you need to compile this as well.
To do that, just add an exception for DeckGL in the `transformignorePatterns`

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!deck\.gl)"]
```

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string

Answer (score 12):

It was work around #1 on [this page](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-06/jest/) that fixed it for me though workaround #2 on that page is mentioned in above answers so they may also be valid.

"Specify the entry for the commonjs version of the corresponding package in the `moduleNameMapper` configuration"

`jest.config.js`

```
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^uuid$": require.resolve("uuid"), 
        "^jsonpath-plus$": require.resolve("jsonpath-plus") 
...
```

Answer (score 11):

In my case I use this config in the file package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "!node_modules/"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Does Jest really give special meaning to a preceding `!` in `transformIgnorePatterns`? I'd guess this is effectively equivalent to writing `transformIgnorePatterns: []`.

Comment: Great answer. FYI if you want to exclude everything but your workspace you can write the pattern like this: `"!node_modules/(?!@src/*.)"`

Answer (score 6):

I was having this issue with a monorepo. A package in the root `node_modules` was breaking my tests. I fixed by changing my local `.babelrc` file to `babel.config.js`. Explanation: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6053#issuecomment-383632515

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It worked for me after renaming the file and adding the exception for my esm library in `transformIgnorePatterns`!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a monorepo (it contains multiple packages for the frontend and backend).

The package I'm testing imports a file from another package that uses the dependency `uuid`.

All the files are in Typescript (not Javascript).

The package I'm testing has a tsconfig file for testing only, called `tsconfig.test.json`. It has the properties `commonjs` and `allowJs`. Adding `allowJs` solves the problem when importing `uuid`, I don't know why.

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    // Necessary to import dependency uuid using CommonJS
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "jest.config.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading a project that uses a version of babel that reads the config from `.babelrc`, when I upgraded to a newer version I read:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case

> ### What's your use case?
>
> You are using a monorepo?
>
> You want to compile node_modules?
>
> [babel.config.json](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#babelconfigjson) is for you!

On top of:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(module))"
    ]
  }
}
```

I renamed `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when using jest with vite+swc and a component using the d3 library (d3-array and d3-shape was having a problem).

This advice to add this to jest.config.js solved it:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@ngrx|(?!deck.gl)|d3-scale)'],
```

This got me wondering why this worked because I don't use ngrx or deck.gl.
But then I noticed that this is equivalent to:

```
 transformIgnorePatterns: ['(?!abc|(?!def))'],
```

The advice also works:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['!node_modules/'],
```

Which led me to the final answer of

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [],
```

Just adding this line with an empty array is the simplest answer which worked.

Comment: When you put: `transformIgnorePatterns: []` That simply mean TypeScript will compile all of `node_modules`, which is a super slow operation if you've got a lot of node modules installed.

Comment: Well that is better than having an error and it not compiling at all. Clearly some issue with one of the dependencies, who knows, maybe they fixed it by now.

Comment: That's not how it works. The world is slowly moving from CommonJS to ES6 modules. That is why this problem exists.

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards Yes we are moving to ES6 modules. You seem to be commenting on something that is 8 months old. I can assure you that I was receiving the error "Jest gives an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"" and the above change worked to remove this error. Perhaps it was slower as you mention, but at least the tests worked. Now the world has moved on and we aren't using the same versions of the libraries anymore, and this isn't a problem anymore. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when using jest 29.7.0 with React 18.

In my case this config worked after changing the `.babelrc` into `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(module))"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me
// .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": "commonjs", // <- Check and see if you have this line
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

jest understands commonJs so it needs babel to transform the code for it before use. Also jest uses caching when running code. So make sure you run `jest --clearCache` before running jest.

Tested Environment:
Node v8.13.0
Babel v6+
Jest v27

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. Library **A** gave such error. I did not use this library in my code directly. I played with jest config a lot of time.
But I found that I forget to mock library **B** in ...test.tsx file. After mocking there was not that error. Sounds pretty stupid but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading 2 projects from Angular 12 to Angular 14 and 15.

After much searching, the ONLY thing that turned both projects in good ones  again was by upgrading the 'Rxjs' package to a newer/newest version. The ONLY thing.

Be sure to have that RxJs upgraded. After that I made sure to have the tslib upgraded as well.

The base Jest configuration was via [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31or_m_xAA0).

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same problem.

```js
export function flatten (target, opts) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I made sure my jest was properly installed and set up, as per [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/testing#jest-and-react-testing-library), but still same issue. None of the popular solutions here were working for me either.

However, while running `npm i`, I noticed this warning:

```bash
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'flat@6.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.1', npm: '8.19.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Since [version 6.0.0](https://github.com/hughsk/flat/releases/tag/v6.0.0), the [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat) package is distributed in ECMAScript modules.

## Solution

The quickest way to fix it was to downgrade it to a version that is compatible with my node.js and my project settings:

```bash
npm i flat@5
```

And since then I've been able to run jest as expected (perhaps updating the node.js version would've solved it too).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
//jest.config.js

    const esModules = [
      'nanoid',
      'p-cancelable',
      'reaflow',
      'easy-email-core',
      'uuid/dist/esm-browser',
      'd3-path/src',
      'd3-shape/src',
    ].join('|');
    
    module.exports = {
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setup.jest.js'],
      globals: {
        Uint8Array: Uint8Array,
      },
      transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
      transform: {
        '^.+.[tj]sx?$': [
          'babel-jest',
        ],
      },
    };
```

In mi case all items within esModules were giving me errors of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"

then

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  // [...]
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }], '@babel/preset-typescript'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The bottom line here did it for me:

```
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': ['ts-jest', { isolatedModules: true, useESM: true }],
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      { useESM: true, tsconfig: { jsx: 'react-jsx' } }
    ],
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': require.resolve('babel-jest')
  }
```

That is, in addition to my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ]
};
```

Hope this helps someone too! I've been using the plasmo framework for building browser extensions--nothing else helped me get Jest going.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same error of importing dataSet from vis-data.js library

```
import { DataSet } from 'vis-data/esnext';
```

So I just removed `/esnext` from the path and now it works:

```
import { DataSet } from 'vis-data';
```