# Jest: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' oauth4webapi

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I'm using an external package called `oauth4webapi` and I can't seem to test it.

In my file where I use it...

```js
import * as o from "oauth4webapi";
```

When testing I get this error:

```js
    /Users/.../node_modules/oauth4webapi/build/index.js:7
    export const clockSkew = Symbol();
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

    > 1 | import * as o from "oauth4webapi";
        | ^
```

The actual file is a `.js` file that uses `export const`.

My `jest.config.ts` is below. I tried:

1. transforming js/jsx files with babel-jest
2. adding all the babel packages in my `.babelrc` didn't work
3. adding transformIgnorePattern for the package to no avail. I tried adding `moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],` along with this option to no avail.
4. Adding `"type": "module"` to my package.json didn't work

```js
// jest.config.ts
import type {Config} from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/49676319
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!(oauth4webapi))"
  ],
};

export default config;
```

My .babelrc I created to try to solve this issue

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

My understading is that this external package uses esm in a `.js` file so it needs to be transformed. How can I do that in my `jest.config.ts` as all the things I've tried didn't work

Comment: Same question, I fight via transformIgnorePatterns and `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` but it works fail. And have you resolve it?

Comment: @taoliujun Use the `tsx` package. Works out of the box