error testing custom backstage plugins with jest
I am a new tester testing backstage components and I am having problems with jest when processing them because of the following issues:
I'm testing with typescript and I'm trying to test external backstage plugins where they are compiled in a .esm.js file. I have tried a thousand ways of configuring jest with babel but it still doesn't work. The error in question
Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token
    
Jest failed to parse a file. This happens, for example, when your code or dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
    
 By default, Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
    
By default the “node_modules” folder is ignored by transformers.

This is what you can do:

If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript.
To have some of your “node_modules” files transformed, you can specify a custom “transformIgnorePatterns” in your config.
If you need a custom transformation, specify a “transform” option in your config.
If you want to simulate non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets), you can remove them with the “moduleNameMapper” config option.

Details:

C:\INCIBE\incibe-r01-svsm-app-tests\node_modules@backstage\core-plugin-api\dist\index.esm.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,dirname,filename,jest){export { AnalyticsContext } from './analytics/AnalyticsContext.esm.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Any help? plis
// jest.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\.esm\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!@module-name\plugin-search).+\.esm.js$',
    '/node_modules/(?!@backstage).+\.esm.js$'
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./Unit-tests/src/setupTests.ts'],
  testMatch: ['*/?(.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)'],
};

//babel.config.json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react" // Si estás utilizando React
  ]
}

//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["./Unit-tests/src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

my intention is to be able to run the tests taking into account that all plugins are exported via .esm.js

This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263429/jest-gives-an-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export
